# How to extract a list of substrings using recursion?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list, python-2.7

Given a string say,
`strr = "int a; int b; int c;"`
How can I extract a list from this string containing elements like `['int a', 'int b', 'int c']`.
I want to achieve this output with recursion and no RegEx at all. Please guide.

Comment: but why recursion?

Comment: You could just use ```strr.split(';')```?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though there are simpler methods, a solution using recursion is as follows.

```
def extract(s):
    ' finds substrings delimited by ; '
    try:
        index = s.index(';')
        # current word + recursion for remainder
        # index + 1 in recursion to skip over ';'
        return [s[:index]] + extract(s[index+1:])
    except:
        # delimiter wasn't found (base case)
        return []
```

*Usage*

```
strr = "int a; int b; int c;"
print(list(extract(strr)))           # Need list to get all element of generator
# Output: ['int a', ' int b', ' int c']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use built-in `split` and 'strip` functions:

```
l = strr.split(';')
l = [x.strip() for x in l]
l.remove('')
```

output:

```
['int a', 'int b', 'int c']
```